# Printing list in Python with serial numbers

Tags: python, list

I have a alphanumeric list variable for example

```
a = ['dwe','fw4fe4f','gvfes','fw4f',44,'vwe4d','sv','vsed']
```

To print all, I use

```
for each in a:
    print each
```

Now I want serial number also added to the each element. so that it can print like.

```
1.dwe
2.fw4fe4f
3.gvfes
```

& so on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate)

```
a = ['dwe','fw4fe4f','gvfes','fw4f',44,'vwe4d','sv','vsed']
for i,each in enumerate(a,start=1):
    print ("{}.{}".format(i,each))
```

Output ..

```
1.dwe
2.fw4fe4f
3.gvfes
4.fw4f
5.44
6.vwe4d
7.sv
8.vsed
```

Comment: Thanks Buddy, enumerate works.

Answer (score 2):

```py
a = ['dwe','fw4fe4f','gvfes','fw4f',44,'vwe4d','sv','vsed']

for i,j in enumerate(a):
    print "%s. %s"%(i+1,j)

>> 1. dwe
   2. fw4fe4f
   3. gvfes
   4. fw4f
   5. 44
   6. vwe4d
   7. sv
   8. vsed
```